# DateTime Picker control for asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using asp.net webforms.There is no date time picker control provided. Presently I'm using a textbox to display datetime. I want a date time picker control. I tried to google, couldn't find a solution. Everything google gives is paid control made by different companies.

I tried searching for a solution to find free date time picker control. I'm not successful. I want a solution to get a free date time picker control.I'm able to get a date picker control by adding type=date on a regular textbox. But date and time picker control is what I want.
Edit:
I added datetime-local. It gives me a date time picker control. Awesome!
      `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateTime" runat="server" type="datetime-local"></asp:TextBox>`

I'm almost close to a solution. I still have one small issue which I need help though. The date time format it outputs is little weird. The output for the selected date for nov 2, 2023, 5 pm is 2023-11-02T17:00. The output is totally weird. The output is in yyyy-mm-dd format. There is an additional T added just before the time. I need a help from the community now. I want to insert this value in a sql server database. In this present format, that is 2023-11-02T17:00, I can't insert this value into database. Can someone help me convert this weird format into database friendly date time?

Comment: Why are you still using WebForms in 2023? It's been effectively obsolete since ASP.NET MVC came out in 2008, that's **15 years ago**...

Comment: Anyway, just use  `<input type="datetime-local" />` (and make sure you take the user's timezone into consideration)

Comment: @Dai I did. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind there is  date option for a text box, and from the toolbox, there is also a calendar control. See my post and answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's correct some false statements here.

quote:

> there is no date time picker control provided.

***Wrong!!!! There is most certainly here is a built in calendar control you can use, and there is ALSO options for the standard text box control.***

Let's first use the standard text box control.

When you drag + drop in a text box to the webform, then note the property sheet settings for that text box.  These ones:

[image]

So, there are all kinds of choices (time picker, password, number and more),  and there are several date choices. So, in above, we choose date from the drop down.

So, say with this markup:

```
        <h3>Enter a date</h3>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
          TextMode="Date"   >

        </asp:TextBox>

        <h3>Code behind button test</h3>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            Text="Test date value - code behind"
            CssClass="btn myshadow"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />
```

And code behind so far is this simple stub:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Debug.Print($"Value of text box (date) = {TextBox1.Text}")

End Sub
```

So, running the above, we get/see this:

[image]

And for output window, we see this:

[image]

(I hit the button 2 times).

I should also point out that if you typing in markup (as opposed to using the property sheet as shown above), then you can type in textmode, hit = and then hit ctrl-space (as always for inteli-sense), and again  you get the list of options for the text box.

This:

[image]

So, CLEARLY without any add-ins, without any JavaScript code, asp.net supports and has a date picker ability out of box. Note how the date displays in the browsers local time, but to get (or set) the text box, you need to use ISO date format.

So, say on page load, I could have the date "default" for today like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    End If

End Sub
```

(note the all important test for isPostBack, since we ONLY want such defaults and setup code to run on first page load - not for additional post-backs.

Next up, if you look at the tool box, you should see a calendar control

This one:

[image]

So, we could drag that onto the web page, but that calendar control is not a auto-popup control, but remains in full view, so you might say drag 2 copies onto the web page. Not that the calendar control has EXTENSIVE formatting options like for weekdays, weekend, today, and more.

So, we drag + drop 2 of the controls onto the form, and we now have this markup:

```
            <div style="float: left">
                <h4>Select Start Date</h4>

                <asp:Calendar ID="dtStart" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px"
                    BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
                    <DayHeaderStyle Height="40px" />
                    <DayStyle BorderStyle="Solid"
                        BorderColor="Black"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        HorizontalAlign="Right"
                        VerticalAlign="Top" Height="40px" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" />
                    <SelectorStyle CssClass="btn-info" />

                    <TitleStyle Height="40px" />

                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="LightSkyBlue" />
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="Ivory" Height="30px" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>


            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px">
                <h4>Select End Date</h4>

                <asp:Calendar ID="dtEnd" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px"
                    BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
                    <DayHeaderStyle Height="40px" />
                    <DayStyle BorderStyle="Solid"
                        BorderColor="Black"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        HorizontalAlign="Right"
                        VerticalAlign="Top" Height="40px" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" />
                    <SelectorStyle CssClass="btn-info" />

                    <TitleStyle Height="40px" />

                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="LightSkyBlue" />
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="Ivory" Height="30px" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>
```

And when we run the above, we have this:

[image]

And the code behind can be this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Debug.Print($"Value of text box (date) = {TextBox1.Text}")
    Debug.Print($"Value of Start calendar = {dtStart.SelectedDate}")
    Debug.Print($"Value of End calendar = {dtEnd.SelectedDate}")

End Sub
```

And output:

[image]

(note how the calendar control DOES return a datetime data type).

So, you can use a text box, just set the TextMode="date".

And as noted, you can also use a calendar control.

So yes, asp.net textbox has a date mode. (it also has a time mode too!!!).

And as above shows, from the toolbox, there is also a calendar control you can use.

Comment: Thank you. I never knew about TextMode. TextMode = DateTimeLocal gives a date time picker control. So simple. Your examples are clean and easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateTime" runat="server" type="datetime-local"></asp:TextBox>
```

This line does the trick. type=datetime-local added the date time picker. Just an easy solution. But the TextBoxDateTime.Text gives out the value in ISO string format. To convert it into .NET datetime, use the following code.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxDateTime.Text, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

Comment: You  don't don't need any tricks at a all, just use the textmode option of a simple standard text box, and it will return the date in ISO format for you always.